# How to replace null values within a row by its first element using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have random `NaN` values and I want to replace it with the first element of the row. How to proceed?

Comment: any examples of dataframes, your attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`fillna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method to do this and passing the `method` keyword argument based on whether you want to use the last valid entry or the next valid entry to fill the NaN. Note this method returns a copy of the data frame and only modifies the original if `inplace` is set to `True`.

Since you want to do this for a row, you can transpose your data frame first and use the corresponding index (a column after transposition) with the `fillna()` method.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
# Insert random NaN values
df['A'][np.random.randint(0, 10, 3)] = np.nan
df['B'][np.random.randint(0, 10, 3)] = np.nan
df['C'][np.random.randint(0, 10, 3)] = np.nan
```

Now `df` should look like this:

```
>>> df
          A         B         C
0  0.978618  0.799159       NaN
1  0.780529  0.118274       NaN
2  0.143353  0.944669  0.521848
3       NaN  0.264556  0.774234
4       NaN  0.568434  0.018790
5  0.617635       NaN       NaN
6  0.943748  0.681820  0.359508
7  0.437032       NaN  0.060225
8       NaN  0.670638  0.210383
9  0.128926  0.315428  0.363711
```

Now you can fill the NaN values of an arbitrary row as described above (note the *transposition*), like so:

```
>>> df.T[7].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Now the NaN in the row is filled with the previous last valid value and can be seen in the data frame:

```
>>> df
          A         B         C
0  0.978618  0.799159       NaN
1  0.780529  0.118274       NaN
2  0.143353  0.944669  0.521848
3       NaN  0.264556  0.774234
4       NaN  0.568434  0.018790
5  0.617635       NaN       NaN
6  0.943748  0.681820  0.359508
7  0.437032  0.437032  0.060225
8       NaN  0.670638  0.210383
9  0.128926  0.315428  0.363711
```

Comment: Thanks, I was reviewing and marked your answer correct that I forgot earlier. Thanks again.